# Why can't I get the argument count of a template function at compile-time?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, static-assert

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename... Types>
constexpr std::size_t getArgCount(Types&&...) noexcept
{
    return sizeof...(Types);
}

struct A
{
    int n;

    void f()
    {
        static_assert(getArgCount(n) > 0); // not ok, why?
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    static_assert(getArgCount(n) > 0); // ok
}
```

**Why can't I get the argument count of a template function at compile-time?**

error message:

```
1>test.cpp
1>test.cpp(17,45): error C2131:  expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>test.cpp(17,42): message :  failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
1>test.cpp(17,42): message :  see usage of 'this'
```

Comment: It seems you have to make the data member `n` `constexpr`.

Comment: Note the main body is ok, where n is also not constexpr.

Comment: I'm not sure; things become complex when involving `this` pointer.

Comment: For some reason, if you add `int n = this->n;` to `f()`, the first assertion works as well.

Comment: It works too with `A().n` and `&A::n`, but not with `std::declval<A>().n`.

Comment: Something weird is going on. In `main`, `n + 1` doesn't work even if you initialize `n` (compilers whine about it not being `constexpr`), but `&n` does work even though it's not `constexpr`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anything that accesses `this` outside `constexpr` context is **not** a constant expression, as defined in [[expr.const]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.1):

> An expression e is a *core constant expression* **unless** the evaluation of *e*, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - `this`, except in a `constexpr` function or a `constexpr` constructor that is being evaluated as part of *e*;

(We need `this` to access `n` in order to pass it to `getArgCount` by reference)

So that's why the first case doesn't compile.

The second case compiles because it doesn't involve an [lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.7) of a non-constant (`sizeof(n)` does not actually "read" `n`).

To demonstrate this, the following will also compile:

```
struct A
{
    int n;

    void f()
    {
        int m = n;
        static_assert(getArgCount(m) > 0); // ok, m doesn't need `this`
    }
};
```

Note: Having a reference inside a `constexpr` context (the `Types&&` part) by itself doesn't break "constexpr-ness" if the lifetime of the reference began within that context: [[expr.const]/2.11.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11.2).

Another example:

```
struct A
{
    int n;

    void f()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(n) > 0); // ok, don't need this for sizeof(A::n)
    }
};
```

The following won't compile:

```
    int n = 1;
    static_assert(getArgCount(n+1) > 0); // not ok, (n+1) "reads" n
```

Comment: This is probably it. This explains why `int n = 1; static_assert(getArgCount(&n));` does work (even though `&n` is not constexpr, there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion).